# Cannot create output in storage job in Azure Streaming Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to add an output in my storage job with the Azure Stream Analytics tool. When I enter in all the necessary information and press "create", nothing happens. I have triple checked that I have all the information accurately, and I am receiving no errors, but it is just that nothing is happening.

Can someone please help?

Karl

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. This is a glitch with the new azure portal. It works by going to the classic portal.